# Dependency Injection problem with IMemoryCache

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am creating a .net core 3.1 Worker Service application. I have a class that has dependency injection using the IMemoryCache interface.  I have the following constructor for the class:

```
 public ItemCache(IMemoryCache cache, string ConnectionString)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        connectionString = ConnectionString;
    }
```

My code uses the GetOrCreateAsync method to create the entries for the cache:

```
 public async Task<OrderItem> GetItem(string itemId, string clientName)
    {
        //check for item in cache, if not there grab it from the database add it and return
        return await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync(itemId, async entry =>
        {
            entry.SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(8));
            return await GetItemFromDB(itemId, clientName);
        });
    }
```

Now in order to inject this, I created the following extension:

```
public static class ItemCacheExtensions
{
    public static void AddItemCache(this IServiceCollection Services, string ConnectionString, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        Services.AddSingleton(services => new ItemCache(cache, ConnectionString));
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is in the Program.cs file adding the service in the CreateHostBuilder method:

```
services.AddItemCache(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("XXXXXX"));
```

I'm struggling to find out how to pass in the IMemoryCache in the call so it gets initialized when the service is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get it using another overload of method `AddSingleton` that accepts `IServiceProvider` as parameter:

```
serivces.AddSingleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>();

public static class ItemCacheExtensions
{
    public static void AddItemCache(this IServiceCollection Services, string ConnectionString, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        Services.AddSingleton<ItemCache>(serviceProvider => {
           var cache = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMemoryCache));
           return new ItemCache(cache, ConnectionString);
        });
    }
}
```

You can find more information about it in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider___0__)

Comment: This is close to what I found.  I also did this  Services.AddSingleton(services => new ItemCache(services.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>(), ConnectionString)); and it worked as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @john Thank you. Yes that should do it, still I prefer to explicitly state the type of generic type parameter `T` in `AddSingleton<T>` because it makes the code more readable. When you have say 100 of `AddSingleton(s => new ...)` it takes a bit of extra time to understand what is actually registered there

Answer (score 2):

So in addition to how @Fabjan shows, you can also just simply inject `IConfiguration` into your `ItemCache` constructor and access it there instead of a string for the connection string

```cs
public ItemCache(IMemoryCache cache, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("XXXXXX");
    }
```

And then just register your `ItemCache` normally:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ItemCache>();
```